# Accessing class variables in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing Class Veriables in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750868/accessing-class-veriables-in-c)

Hi I have following class hierarchy in C++

```
Class1 {  
    vector<Class2> vecClass2;  
}  

Class2 {  
    private:  
        const Class1 * ptrClass1;  
        vector<Class3> vecClass3;  
    public:  
        Class2(const Class1 * ptrClass1);  
        int intC2publicVar;  
        string strC2publicVar;  
}  

Class3 {  
    private:  
        const Class2 * ptrClass2;  
        vector<Class4> vecClass4;  
    public:  
        Class3(const Class2 * ptrClass2);  
}  

Class4 {  
    private:  
        const Class3 * ptrClass3;  
        vector<Class5> vecClass5;  
    public:  
        Class4(const Class3 * ptrClass3);  
        void class4Method() const;  
}
```

In class4Method() I am doing something like this:

```
void Class4::class4Method() const {  
    const Class2 * pC2 = ptrClass3->ptrClass2;  
    int valClass2 = pC2->intC2publicVar;  
    //Above value is giving wrong value, I have no idea from where it is fetching the wrong value  

    string strVatClass2 = pC2->strC2publicVar;  
    //Above line of code cause run time termination of code and programs stops as soon as this line executes.  

    const Class2 c2 = * pC2;  
    //Above line of code cause run time termination of code and programs stops as soon as this line executes.  

}
```

I have no idea why this is happening in class4Method() of Class4. Please help me how to solve this. My whole project is struck due to this problem and I could not move further without solving it.

Comment: Have you initialized the data member pointers?

Comment: first line in your method: `const Class2 * pC2 = ptrClass3->ptrClass2;` you access private member of `Class3`. This should not compile. Anything after that is moot from the runtime perspective.

Comment: Agreed, I don't think you posted the code you're "running" :p Also, you should probably avoid talking about heirarchies unless you're using inheritance between classes (did you by any chance forget to put the inheritance relationships in this?).

Comment: Show us how you have initialized that Class3 instance.

Comment: You also complain that you don't know what the variable is (`pC2->intC2publicVar`), but don't show how you initialise the classes.

Comment: The code you have posted is correct. If you are not getting the right values it is because you have a bug somewhere else in your code. Possibly in the part of the code where you set up the data. Possibly because you have issues with copying your objects. Anyway need to see more code.

Comment: @juanchopanza As you can see that I am passing the classes in the pointers. I am initializing the class in the constructor

Comment: You don't show where and how you initialize the pointers.

Comment: In Class2 there is a method which is creating the instances of Class3 and storing it in the vector. Similarly In Class3 there is a method which created the instances of Class4 and stores it in the vector. Theses methods are also called in the constructors.

Comment: I initialize the pointers in the constructors like Class3(const class2 * _prtClass2){ ptrClass2 = _ptrClass2; }

Comment: What about `intC2publicVar` or `strC2publicVar`? How are you initialising them?

Comment: OK, but need to see the code where you invoke the constructor. There a lots and lots of things you could be doing wrong, and if you are posting one line at a time, this is going to take a *long* time.

Comment: @Fiktik I guess this is the problem. It is compiling but terminates on runtime. So is there any solution to this or I have to declare it public?

Comment: @Mark Ingram The actual code is now above 1000 lines of code so I did not posted the very much completed code but what I can ensure you that intC2publicVar or strC2publicVar are initialized properly in the constructor of CLass2. I print them in Class2 and they print fine there.

Comment: @DanishAltafSatti My guess would be that you are creating pointers to local variables, that would explain why the values print correctly in the constructor, but don't print correctly in the code you posted. But without seeing any more code, only a guess.

Comment: @John In class2 constructor there is a method called which created the objects of class3 and store them in the vector. Similarly in Class3 there is a method which created the objects of Class4 and store them in the vector. This method is also called in the constructor of CLass3. Let me know which part of code should I post further.

Comment: I would like to see the code where you create class2 objects. Specifcally the class2 constructer has a pointer parameter, I would like to see how you create that pointer.

Comment: @john are you sure that this is not the problem due to Class3 member being private as suggested by Fiktik because it does not give any error on compile time but only terminates on runtime?

Comment: If public/private was the problem it would not compile. As Fiktik said the cdoe you posted, should not compile. It's very hard to fix problems when the code posted is only approximately the code being used. So, I'm not really sure of anything.

Comment: @john I pass this pointer parameter using 'this' keyword. Its true in all classes the class which is creating the objects of other class pass its own pointer using 'this' in the constructors.

Comment: @DanishAltafSatti What compiler are you using? I confess I am reluctant to believe there is a C++ compiler that can't properly handle basic member visibility like this.

Comment: In CLass2 it is like  Class3 c3(this); vecClass3.push(c3);

Comment: @DanishAltafSatti I give up, without seeing real code (instead of descriptions of code, and approximations of the real code) I'm afraid it's very difficult to help. If you want SO to fix this problem I suggest you post real, complete code. If necessary reduce the size of your program before you post. Cut it down to a minimal complete program that still has the bug, and them post the whole program. You will get it fixed very quickly that way. At the moment you are just wasting time.

Comment: You are missing semi-colons after each class definition.

Comment: @Derek Exactly, it's not real code. Waste of time.

Comment: @Fiktik I am using g++ compiler

Comment: @Derek just take it as a pseudo-code. Actual code is much larger I can not post complete code here.

Comment: Duplicate of [Accessing Class Veriables in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12750868/491837) Please merge answers.

Answer (score 2):

Do I assume correctly that the `const Class`*N-1*`* ptrClass`*N-1* members are pointers to "owners" of the current instance and that the instance they point to lives in a vector in the `Class`*N-2*?

In that case you simply forgot that vectors have this habit of moving their content around the memory as they reallocate to accommodate newly inserted values. Don't store pointers to objects in vectors but either store the objects in list (and take pointer to the instance in the list, because it's still copied) or store vector of pointers (and make sure you delete the elements in destructor).

Comment: +1, it's a plausible suggestion.

Comment: @Jan yes you are right in your assumption. But there is one thing more. The object are stored in the vector only once and the vectors are not updated afterwards, Only the pointers are retrieved. Can it still cause this problem?

Comment: @Danish Depends on how you fill the vectors. If you just push_back object after object ... then definitely yes.

Comment: @Fiktik I am using push back. This is first time I am doing something in C++ and it seems it is more complex than I initially thought. You don't have to worry for such things in Java.